# Postear en tiempo real con stack de MERN

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

En los ultimos meses hice mis dos primeros proyectos con el stack de MERN, uno de ellos fue algo parecido a un clone de facebook en dondes te registras y puedes hacer posts, ahora, el problema es que, desde otra computadora, no podría ver los cambios en tiempo real de otra persona, tendría que refrescar la pagina para poder ver los cambios en la aplicación, y es algo que me ha estado inquietando desde entonces....

Cuál sería la tecnología que tendría que aprender para poder hacer ese tipo de cambios en tiempo real? Se que existen los web sockets y socket.io ( del cual he escuchado ), pero solo he visto como funcionaría en un chat, nada más, de resto no se como podría hacer mis aplicaciones, como posts y comentarios, incluso notificaciones en tiempo real

Comment: Las notificaciones si puedes hacerlo con socket.io en cuanto a los post una forma que se me ocurre es cargarlos al hacer scroll o estar cerca así siempre estarán actualizados

Comment: Socket.io no solo sirve para hacer chats, con ello podrías programar eventos de manera que cuando cuando agregues un nuevo post, emitas un evento a tu backend que has hecho un cambio, de esa forma en dicho evento programarías tu lógica para guardar en la BD y luego recuperar los datos y emitirlas nuevamente a los clientes conectados.

Comment: Eniendo, gracias por las respuestas !